# Build x OR (NOT y) Using NAND Gates Only

Tags: logic

I am trying to create a solution to the following using NAND gates only.  How would I go about doing that?

x OR (NOT y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
Not(x) = Nand(x, x)
```

and

```
Or(x, y) = Nand(Not(x), Not(y))
```

That expression can be formed using only `Nand` gates as follows:

```
Nand(Nand(x, x), y)
```

Or, if you prefer the postfix notation:

```
y Nand x Nand x
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers is the following

```
(NOT X) NAND Y
```